# React & Typescript: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello everyone who came to help. The code compiles and works, but TypeScript throws an error that Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number'.
If you look deep into the hook, you can see that the `step` property is of type `number` in its interface.

The error occurs in this entry: step.**id**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import FirstStep from './steps/firstStep'
import {useForm, useStep} from 'react-hooks-helper'

interface IDefaultData2 {
    id: string
}

const steps : any = [
    {id: 'firstStep'},
    {id: 'secondStep'},
    {id: 'thirdStep'},
    {id: 'confirm'},
    {id: 'success'}
]

const UserForm: React.FC = () => {
    const {step, navigation} = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0
    })
    
    console.log(typeof(step))       // object
    console.log(typeof(step.id))    // string
    console.log(step.id)            // "firstStep"
    
    return (
        <>
        {
            (() => {
                switch(step.id){
                    case 'firstStep': return <FirstStep/>
                }
            })()
        }
        </>
    )
}

export default UserForm
```

What doesn't it like?

**SOLUTION**:

1. Add

```
interface useStepType {
    step: any,
    navigation: any,
}
```

2. Edit

**From**

```
const { step, navigation } = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0
    })
```

**To**

```
const { step, navigation }: useStepType = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0
    })
```

Special thanks to **Tomas Gonzalez**

Comment: What is `useStep`?

Comment: Typescript thinks that step is a number but it's actually an object

Comment: @CertainPerformance, 
I am doing multi forms according to the youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuJDKp-9HHc&t=157s. He uses the react-hook-helper hook there.

Where 'useStep' is the new useTrafficLight and is a more general step wizard. You can use it to simplify many tasks, such as a multi-page input form, or an image carousel.
It has an auto advance function, or control manually by calling previous and/or next.

Comment: @user2258152, so how can i fix it? This is the mistake

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] in the question itself, including `useStep`, which looks to be essential to understanding what's going on in the code

Comment: Are you sure this error is coming from this page? Typescript should not throw any error here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that you are setting step as an object and not as a number,

to solve this create a new interface for type step:

```
interface stepType {
    id: string,
}
interface useStepType {
   step: stepType,
   navigation: any,
}
```

and then try to set the step to this type

```
    const {step, navigation}: useStepType = useStep({
    steps,
    initialStep: 0
})
```

Comment: step should be typed as any by default ? but if op wants typing than this the way to do it.

Comment: That would solve the error, but is bad practice and defies the point of typescript. In this case, the step should be an object with one id property. I set navigation as any because I have no information on the structure of the object.

Comment: op did not assigned number to step so I suspect the error is coming from somewhere else in his project.

Comment: I assumed that typescript is inferring step to be a number, but we can overwrite this by declaring the type.

Comment: @TomasGonzalez,In your solution, the past error is gone, but a new one has appeared.
Error text: "Type 'UseStepResponse' is not assignable to type 'useStepType'. Types of property 'step' are incompatible. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'stepType'."
However, the code compiles as well.

I just removed one of your interfaces and set the **step** property to type **any**.

The following happened:

interface useStepType {
    step: any,
    navigation: any,
}
const { step, navigation }: useStepType = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0
    })